# Is a pipeline made of simple commands?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, posix

From Bash Reference Manual

> A pipeline is a sequence of **simple commands** separated by one of the control operators `|` or `|&`.

From POSIX 2013

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more **commands** separated by the control operator `|`.

I know that Bash has many extensions to POSIX shells, e.g. `|&`.

But  are the component commands of a pipeline

- simple commands or
- just any commands (simple, pipeline again, list, compound, and function)?

In Bash, the following works

```
$ for f in $(ls *); do echo $f; done | cat
```

but the first component command of the pipeline isn't simple but compound.

Comment: And just to confuse you more ,`echo` is a built-in command of bash, but there is also `/bin/echo` that does almost exactly the same thing

Comment: you probably want backticks acound the `ls *`,  I tried to edit, but it wouldn't let me make such a minor edit.  Needed more characters.  Put 5 spaces in front of that line, which marks up as 'code',  then you can add the backticks

Answer (score 7):

The manual for Bash 4.4.5 does not contain the word "simple" from the description of what a pipeline is made up of. The "simple command" you're referring to was probably either a typo or an oversight, or possibly a leftover from a long time ago.

It was [fixed by the `bash` maintainer in April 2014](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/doc/bashref.texi?id=e2f12fdf579f8e3ca91c95f4facd7518bf441b25&dt=1), and it currently reads:

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of
>   the control operators `|` or `|&`.

A pipeline can clearly be made up from commands that or not simple commands (for example subshells and `for` loops, which are compound commands).

Comment: Fixed in [the 2014-03-21 snapshot](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/doc/bashref.texi?id=e2f12fdf579f8e3ca91c95f4facd7518bf441b25&context=3&ignorews=0&dt=1)

Answer (score 1):

Bash manual (`man bash`) has never included the word simple in the description of a pipeline. Get any of the `bash-${version}.tar.gz` files [from this site](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/), decompress and take a look at the file `bash-${version}/doc/bash.1` which is the manual of bash for each version.

What has included the word `simple` is the `bashref` file. From the same downloaded and expanded file as above, read `bash-${version}/doc/bashref.pdf`, which has included the word `simple` at point `3.2.2 Pipelines` up to version 4.3 of the said bashref manual.

> 3.2.2 Pipelines
>    A pipeline is a sequence of simple commands separated by … ‘|’ or ‘|&’.

That the bashref included such word has never meant that complex commands (as opposed to "simple") were in any way excluded from being used as part of a pipeline (including `{…}` `if…then…` `while…do…` and others).

Such wording is a simple typo and should not be used to extract any conclusion.